# XMLDocument Load - DTD processing

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I am trying to put together as security demonstration for work and I want to demonstrate why DTD entity processing can be dangerous, and therefore why we want to prevent it. I am trying to get it working in a larger sense but here is the code I am having difficulty with.

```
 String str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><!DOCTYPE foo [<!ELEMENT foo ANY> <!ENTITY xxe    SYSTEM \"http://www.google.com\" >]><root>&xxe;</root>";
        String encoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str);
        System.Xml.XmlDocument xDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(str)
```

The difficulty is that every time I load my xml document I get an exception that the DOCTYPE token was not expected. How do I enable loading a DTD in C# with LoadXml, parse my DTD with entity expansion? without an exception?